# Flutter app is so slower in release build than debug

Tags: flutter

I built an app in flutter which loads data from the server and also fetches 
it based on the user requests. I've noticed a problem recently. My app is 
very slower when loading data in release build than debug one. The app almost gets stuck when loading data 
in release mode but in debug mode, it loads data in less than two seconds. 
Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can fix this?

I'm running the debug build on an Asus laptop with 12g ram win10 and release on samsung m20 and huawi redmi. The app gets stuck on both of physical devices when loading. I don't know what caused this problem in my app. I tested similar apps and they had an acceptable loading speed in both release and debug builds on these devices.

Comment: I now see the same issue. In release I deploy to a real device and it is really laggy everytime it tries to load data. However when I run it on the same device with the debugger attached it runs smooth. I am loading data using sqflite, so no network is used in this case. Did you find a solution? I will try to look into the sqflite thing.

Comment: Run app in profile mode and check cpu profiling in dart dev tools

Comment: any solution to this ??

Comment: see also https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19677 - "Release mode is way more slower than debug mode for user defined functions."

Answer (score 1):

In this kind of situation, I suggest [try to target the APK of your device](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31552#issuecomment-486460578) in which the Flutter app is running. `flutter build apk` will build a 32-bit APK by default.

Example:

> If you want a 64-bit APK then you'll need to specify that as the
> target.
>
> Try using `flutter build apk --target-platform=android-arm64`
>
> `flutter run` will build an APK targeting the attached device. So if
> the device is 64-bit, then `flutter run` will build a 64-bit APK.